# What can google app engine build in to?

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk

I've been looking at this for the past hour and can't find a direct answer. Does this build into a website and anyone who can access a browser have access to it and that's it?

I was curious if it can build for mobile devices like Apple, Android, Windows Phones and also have a web page for it. Pretty much looking for an engine that can build for web/pc + android, apple, windows phones, kindle etc .

Any advice is greatly appreciated, sorry for the newbie question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not getting your question exactly. Are you asking if it's good for cross-mobile-platform development? If you are interested in cros-platform devices development you might want to have a look to PhoneGap  and jQuery mobile.

Comment: Take a look to wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine

Comment: Wow both of those look very interesting and exactly what I'm looking for. A SDK engine that's cross platform but not only for mobile devices. Something I can publish on mobile devices but also have it to build on my own website or facebook or just a google chrome browser store application. Any ideas? Thanks again for your answer!

Comment: Pretty much I want to have it on all mobile devices but also have it available for PC users as well. Is that currently possible?

Comment: The point is: you strictly need that your app is hosted by Google App Engine? Consider reading this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine#Differences_with_other_application_hosting! If not, and if you can use any other web hosting service PhoneGap + jQuery Mobile will work for you. The back-end could be done in PHP, Python, whatever you like. Consider reading this: http://sixrevisions.com/mobile/cross-platform-mobile-apps/

Comment: Hehe so I've been reading for the past 30 minutes all about cross platform development tools since you gave me the perfect term to search. Thanks for that btw. Funny enough it's making me ponder even more. I've made my app in Corona which is Lua only and supports mainly Apple and Android. But many of my users want access to my app on desktops. I don't need to use google engine, I was just reading about it and was wondering if it'd work for me, but seems like there are better options out there. Would you say HTML5 seems like the best option for having it on devices and desktop pc's? Thank you!

Comment: check out bluestacks, it's and android emulator on PC.

Comment: App Engine is a server platform that can provide online services to your PC/Android/iOS/Other apps, and server websites. It is not an app development SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it to build anything that are served from an URL (e.g. http://example.com/something).

That includes web pages, the "backend" for any application that GET/POST something to an http:// - which means any mobile Apps. And anything else you can imagine that make use of http:// to communicate between a client and a server

And a very important requirement, you need to have some programming knowledge in order to use this. Otherwise you should be looking for more general web hosting service.